# PLC to Server to Web

Tags: django, database, connection, plc

First, thank you for reading this

second, I'm a new to all this as i'm fresh out colleges and I'm tasked with developing this project that allows, a plc to read the input (analogue data) at the factory and send its data to the server(A PC) by wireless, at the factory. The Server will then upload the data onto a webpage; where it can be view anywhere, mobile or computer.

Now questions:

1. how do I let server read plc data
2. how do I upload data into the webpage?

I'm using *MITSUBISHI PLC FX3G-14MR/ES-A*

and

The website I'm doing is a *Django framework/python*

Are there tips, any recommendations? or website where I can start?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry I just had too much question at one go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance the following architecture will suite your request, but ofc it is just an example:

- pymodbus (a python module for modbus server/client) to collect data from PLC
- redis for storing values (it has connectors for python and whatever you like)
- for web server you already use python/django. For my purposes i usually use python/twisted for backend and angular for frontend.

Comment: Is redis a database? and pymodbus, is a snippet??

Comment: Man, you just have to google and follow the 1st link. Yes, it is a kind of non-sql database, very useful for exchange between your data-collector process and web back-end. https://redis.io will give you more information. Pymodbus, as I wrote, is a python library to facilitate modbus communication

Comment: alright, thanks for information Grapes. Thank you for the advice